# need support defining the right regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I would like to parse a file using `boost::sregex_token_iterator`.

Unfortunately I'm not able to find the right regex to extract strings in the form `FOO:BAR` out of it.

The below code example is usable only if one such occurence per line is found, but I would like to support multiple of this entries per line, and ideally also a comment after an '#'

So entries like this

```
AA:BB CC:DD EE:FF #this is a comment
```

should result in 3 identified token (AA:BB, CC:DD, EE:FF)

```
boost::regex re("((\\W+:\\W+)\\S*)+");
boost::sregex_token_iterator i(line.begin(), line.end(), re, -1), end;

for(; i != end; i++){
  std::stringstream ss(*i);
  ...
}
```

Any support is very welcome.

Comment: the code example was incomplete :(

Comment: It is not possible to have a variable number of capture groups in regex. What I would do is start by splitting using `#` and take the first result, resulting in everything before the `#`. Then split using white space, this will result in individual pairs. These can then be split further using `:`.

Comment: I agree with @SchoolBoy. What can be done through splits should rarely be done through regex.

Comment: Since you're already using boost, I'd consider writing a simple parser using spirit.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match sequences of 1 or more word chars followed with `:` and then having again 1 or more word chars.

Thus, you need to replace `-1` with `1` in the call to [`boost::sregex_token_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_token_iterator.html) to get *Group 1* text chunks and replace the regex you use with `\w+:\w+` pattern:

```
boost::regex re(R"(#.*|(\w+:\w+))");
boost::sregex_token_iterator i(line.begin(), line.end(), re, 1), end;
```

Note that `R"(#.*|(\w+:\w+))"` is a raw string literal that actually represents `#.*|(\w+:\w+)` pattern that matches `#` and then the rest of the line or matches and captures the pattern you need into Group 1.

See an [`std::regex` C++ example](https://ideone.com/4mVK1e) (you may easily adjust the code for Boost):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex r(R"(#.*|(\w+:\w+))");
        std::string s = "AA:BB CC:DD EE:FF #this is a comment XX:YY";
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        std::cout << m[1].str() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This does not meet the requirement of allowing `#`s to represent comments.

Comment: @SchoolBoy It does not really have to. There are no `XX:YY` inside the comment.

Comment: But there might be from what I understand.

Comment: @SchoolBoy Then I'd rather refrain from regex at all.

Comment: Hence my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use splitting to get the values you need.

I would begin by first splitting using `#`. This separates the comment from the rest of the line. Then split using white space, which separates the pairs out. After this, individual pairs can be split using `:`.

If, for whatever reason, you must use regex, you can iterate over the matches. In this case I would use the following regex:

```
(?:#(?:.*))*(\w+:\w+)\s*
```

This regex will match every pair until it finds a comment. If there is a comment, it will skip to the next new line.

Comment: Thanks all of you for your kind support. Wiktor's solution works perfect.